# App crashes if the view disappears while the UiTableView is being reloaded

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a view with the list of entities pulled from a remote source (via web-service). App crashes, if back button is pressed (view with tableview disappears) while the entities are being loaded on to the table view.

Answer (score 1):

If any keyboard appeared, resign the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks @Shebin for the reply, but no keyboard appears on the screen. It is a plain list of items.

Answer (score 0):

What about using NSOperation to retrieve the data from your Web Service, and cancel it if the user press the back button?

http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Another Option would be to check the view in the completion handler (when your data is ready)

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop the remote service call in viewWillDisappear (or) use IgnoringInteractionEvents up to that page load.